# A desert for odoo folks: filter partners in mail.wizard.invite

Tags: odoo

I want to extend the mail module so i can add a little functionality : invite only followers that are employees.(social networking)

in other words:

```
for record in res.partners
    user=self.env['res.users'].search([('partner_id',"=",record.ID)])
    employee=self.env['hr.employee'].search([('user_id',"=",user.ID)])
    get the employee information and stock it somewhere
```

someone to help me to translate this in python x)

Comment: first i want to be sur that this operation is possible, whant can you say about it?

Comment: sure, it's possible.

Comment: i solved the problem here is the solution:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36578587/mixing-apples-and-oranges-3-odoo8