# Mixing apples and oranges :3 odoo8

Tags: odoo

I'm trying to send notification to employees, i created a computed many2many field to get the partners id and pass them to partner_ids field of the mail.wizard.invite model.

here is my inherited class:

```
from openerp import models, fields, api
class CustMailInvite(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'mail.wizard.invite'
    employee_ids=fields.Many2many('hr.employee','employees')

    @api.one
    @api.depends('employee_ids.user_id.partner_id')
    def compute_partner_ids(self):
        for a in self.employee_ids:
            if a.user_id:
                if a.user_id.partner_id:
                    self.partner_ids += a.user_id.partner_id.id


    partner_ids=fields.Many2many('res.partner',compute='compute_partner_ids')
```

I'm getting this error:

ValueError

Mixing apples and oranges: res.partner() + 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from openerp import models, fields, api
class CustMailInvite(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'mail.wizard.invite'
    employee_ids=fields.Many2many('hr.employee','employees')

    @api.one
    @api.depends('employee_ids.user_id.partner_id')
    def compute_partner_ids(self):
        for a in self.employee_ids:
            if a.user_id:
                if a.user_id.partner_id:
                    self.partner_ids+=a.user_id.partner_id




    partner_ids=fields.Many2many('res.partner',compute='compute_partner_ids')
```

the problem was in this line self.partner_ids+=a.user_id.partner_id.id, I changed to self.partner_ids+=a.user_id.partner_id